# Is there a way to compile typescript into es6 but force it to use requirejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, module

I am writing a NodeJS typescript project. Let's say I have the following file:

```js
class MyArray extends Array {
   myCustomMethod() { /* do something */ }
}
```

However, when I do

```js
let myarray = new MyArray();

myarray.myCustomMethod();
```

I see

```
TypeError: myarray.myCustomMethod is not a function
```

So, I tried to change the typescript `module` to es6 (so that it will keep the `class extends` syntax), but then it uses the `import` and `export` keyword, and NodeJS doesn't support that natively.

Is there a way to force the typescript compiler to use requirejs but also use es6?

Or is it my bad and I am missing something?

Comment: What makes you think it's a module problem?

Comment: when I write the same code in plain JS it runs fine and there is no problem, which leads me to think that the compiled TS is the problem, and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript's `--module` option (also `-m`) lets you specify what module system it should output for. `"CommonJS"` is the variant that uses `require`. Details in the [project configuration options documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

So for instance, in `tsconfig.json`, `"module": "CommonJS"` combined with `"target": "ES2015"` (or `"ES2020"` or `"ESNext"`, etc.) should output code using `require` and also `class` syntax.

Comment: Yes, but when it uses commonjs it does not use the es6 class syntax, which I think is the problem.

Comment: @ezra - No, that's a different option called `--target`, also documented by the page linked above.

Comment: ok, thanks. setting it to `"target": "es6"` fixed the issue

Comment: @ezra - Excellent! Beware that `"ES6"` is `"ES2015"`, which is fairly out of date these days. These days, if a browser supports ES2015, it's likely to support at least ES2018 if not beyond.

Comment: cool! I will update it then. Edit: does Node support es2018 as well? (14.4)

Comment: @ezra - v14.4 supports at least ES2019 and probably most if not all of ES2020 as well. :-) For specifics, look up the thing you want to use on MDN and look at the compat data, it calls out Node.js separately from browsers. For instance, [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), new in ES2020, was supported in v14.0.0.